# How can I navigate a page in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have this code in Xaml :

```
<Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
```

And this code in code-behind :

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

}
```

How can I navigate a page in this method ?

Comment: What do you mean with "redirect"? Navigating to another page?

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure that your app is based on a `NavigationPage` to enable navigation in Xamarin.Forms. For this, set the `MainPage` property of your `App.cs` to a `NaviationPage` instance.

```
public App()
{           
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourStartPage());
}
```

Now add a second `Forms Xaml Page` or `Forms ContentPage` to your project, that you can navigate to from your start page. Make sure, your `OnButtonClicked` handler is declared as **`async`** (like in the sample below) and navigate like this:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
}
```

Comment: Just add the async modifier that's it

Comment: Okey I used like this but I get this error message : PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: Yeah, you need to wrap your whole app into a `NavigationPage` inside your `App.cs`. I updated my answer to make clear, what's to do.